# Lucene.Net TermQuery wildcard search

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I have a lucene index I am trying to do a wildcard search.
In index i have a character like
`'234Test2343'`
I am trying to do the search like %Test%..

My lucene syntax looks like

```
string catalogNumber="test";
Term searchTerm = new Term("FIELD", "*"+catalogNumber+"*");
Query query = new TermQuery(searchTerm);
```

I don't get the results back. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [WildCardQuery](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/d1b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_wildcard_query.html). A TermQuery looks for the literal asterisk, rather than a wild card. Please note that a WildCardQuery's performance is usually very slow, probably more so when using two wild cards as you do.

Comment: looks like it gives me back top 100 results? is there a way to get more than 100 results?

Comment: Could you please add the search commands to your code snippet above?
This way I may be able to answer the number of hits question.

Comment: sorry @RanchMobile, I couldn't find a replacement link. https://lucenenet.apache.org/index.html is the current root web page for lucene.net.